# Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable when trying to return jwt_token

Tags: python, django, twilio

Really confused because this functionality was working a few days ago and I made no substantial changes to my code.

I am getting this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 105, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

To summarize, I am sending a name to the Twilio library with the expectation of receiving a JWT_token. The API endpoint would then return a dict with a key: title and jwt_token

This is what my view for the end point looks like:

```
class TokenView(View):
    def get(self, request, username, *args, **kwargs):
        voice_grant = grants.VoiceGrant(
            outgoing_application_sid=settings.TWIML_APPLICATION_SID,
            incoming_allow=True,
        )
        access_token = AccessToken(
            settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
            settings.TWILIO_API_KEY,
            settings.TWILIO_API_SECRET,
            identity=username
        )
        access_token.add_grant(voice_grant)
        jwt_token = access_token.to_jwt()
        full_data = {'token': jwt_token}
        # print(type(jwt_token))
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(full_data), content_type="application/json", safe=False)
```

I've also tried to have this in the return statement:

```
JsonResponse({"token": jwt_token})
```

Comment: Yes; `jwt_token` is a `bytes` object, which cannot be serialized to JSON by default, because it is ambiguous what the result should be like. By nature, JSON is a text-based format, using UTF-8 text encoding. The correct way to handle the problem depends on the specification for `access_token.to_jwt()`. If it can create arbitrary binary data, better to use some encoding such as base64 first.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel do you mind adding that as an answer?

Comment: I don't think it's specific enough to answer the question (and I don't think the question is specific enough to be answered yet). Depending on *what the specification is*, I can probably link you an existing duplicate. To be, clear, does the `.to_jwt` method produce one of [these](https://jwt.io/)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, it does. It produces an encoded JSON object with three parts: the header, the payload, and the signature.

Comment: Encoded how? As base64?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel According to the doc's HS256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access_token.to_jwt()` returns a `byte`, simply decode the token: `access_token.to_jwt().decode()`

Full code:

```
class TokenView(View):
    def get(self, request, username, *args, **kwargs):
        voice_grant = grants.VoiceGrant(
            outgoing_application_sid=settings.TWIML_APPLICATION_SID,
            incoming_allow=True,
        )
        access_token = AccessToken(
            settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
            settings.TWILIO_API_KEY,
            settings.TWILIO_API_SECRET,
            identity=username
        )
        access_token.add_grant(voice_grant)
        jwt_token = access_token.to_jwt()
        full_data = {'token': jwt_token.decode()}
        # print(type(jwt_token))
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(full_data), content_type="application/json", safe=False)
```

That should work.